# SDN for wireless network

Tags: cisco, wireless, osi, sdn

I have been reading about Software-Defined Networking (SDN) for a while. I have a question: Is SDN made only for wired networks capability? I wonder if SDN can be utilized in wireless networks.

Comment: You have asked a few questions, and you have received good answers on some, but you have not accepted any answers. The questions will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer, until you accept an answer on the questions.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise wireless networks that use "dumb" access points and a centralized controller are actually a very good example of Software Defined Networking.

Answer (score 1):

Following generalized SDN concept, wireless controller and thin APs are SDN-like products. They use the same southbound protocol (like CAPWAP) to communicate each others. Some wireless controller product provide northbound API (like RESTful API) to other application.